# Joint end-to-end learning of Keras and Theano parameters

Tags: deep-learning, theano, keras

I want to build a deep neural network composed of a couple of CNNs and an RNN. The CNNs are vggNet which can be easily implemented using Keras. However, the RNN structure is different from a simple vanilla RNN, and in the first look I found it difficult to hack into the Keras code to inherit my own custom RNN layer from the simpleRNN class. On the other hand, I think implementing this RNN using pure Theano is much easier and less complicated (based on this [code](https://github.com/dennybritz/rnn-tutorial-rnnlm/blob/master/rnn_theano.py)).

I was wondering if there is any way to jointly train the whole network when it is partially implemented using Keras and pure Theano, and learn their parameters together. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a way to implement it ?

Comment: No, but now you can easily do this with Tensorflow.

Comment: Any example or link please ?

Comment: https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html

Comment: you were talking about tenseroflow, can I see that part ?

Comment: For instance refer to "II: Using Keras models with TensorFlow" in the above link.

Comment: we are talking about join training between cnn and rnn, what is this link should refer to ?

Comment: I meant you can conveniently use Keras and Tensorflow. In order to define an RNN in Tensorflow, you can refer to Tensorflow documentation.

Comment: This is not the question.